Limited access to photos giving full access on iOS, when using image_picker on flutter
I want to upload user's selected photo to server using image_picker plugin for flutter. But, when user is selecting limited access to photos and selecting photos that can be visible to app, it is showing full library with all photos.
I am using image_picker with this code:
      final ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();

      // Check for gallery permission
      final hasPermission = await requestPhotosPermission();

      if (!hasPermission) return false;

      final photoResult = await imagePicker.pickImage(
          source: ImageSource.gallery,
          maxHeight: 1280,
          maxWidth: 800,
          requestFullMetadata: false);

I have added permissions to info.plist as well
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Access to the photo library is necessary.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Access to the photo library is necessary.</string>

Below is an error log after selecting photos and click done. It is showing all photos rather then selected ones.
**[core] "Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "(null)""
[PAAccessLogger] Failed to log access with error: access=<PATCCAccess 0x283311110> accessor:<<PAApplication 0x283311120 identifierType:auditToken identifier:{pid:1112, version:3545}>> identifier:D4D1111-F111-4798-1111-F1911111A9E0 kind:intervalEvent timestampAdjustment:0 visibilityState:0 assetIdentifierCount:0 tccService:kTCCServicePhotos, error=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service with pid 226 named com.apple.privacyaccountingd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service with pid 226 named com.apple.privacyaccountingd}**

Any solutions? Thanks.

You don't need to request any access to the users photo library. You are using PHPickerViewController This controller allows the user to select the image that they want to make available to your app. The asset is then delivered to your app. Photo library access allows your app to access items in the photo library directly, without user interaction, which is why permission is needed.

@Paulw11 I have removed NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription from info.plist. Now, when I trying to select a photo from gallery, the app is crashing and here is the error - This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data

You need the permission string as documented on the plug-in, but you don't need to explicitly request permissions and you don't have full access to the users photo library.

After researching I have found that I don't need to ask permission for image_picker plugin. Therefore, for not getting error with full photos permission even when we gave limited photos permission - just don't ask it at all. Maybe, on some devices even on shared area photos can be restricted and it needs permission, by that way, I don't know how to fix it.
